Deriving a high order Derivative formula for fractional variable
Let $f\in C^{(\infty)}(\Bbb{R})$. Show that for $x\ne 0$:
$$\frac{1}{x^{n+1}}f^{(n)}\left(\frac 1x\right)=(-1)^n\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(x^{n-1}f\left(\frac 1x\right)\right)$$
I think a possible approach to prove this is by induction, but I haven't found a way through the derivation. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

By induction on $n$.
The case $n=1$ is clear, so let us suppose the thesis is true for each $m\leq n-1$ and we prove it for $n$.
Then
$$(-1)^n\frac{d^n}{d^n x}(x^{n-1}f(\frac{1}{x}))=(-1)^n\frac{d^{n-1}}{d^{n-1}x}\left( (n-1)x^{n-2}f(\frac{1}{x}) -x^{n-3}f'(\frac{1}{x})\right)=(n-1)\frac{d^{n-1}}{d^{n-1}x}\left((-1)^{n-2}x^{n-2}f(\frac{1}{x})\right)+\frac{d^{n-1}}{d^{n-1}x}\left((-1)^{n-3}x^{n-3}f'(\frac{1}{x}) \right)= -(n-1)\frac{d^{n-1}}{d^{n-1}x}\left((-1)^{n-1}x^{n-2}f(\frac{1}{x})\right)- \frac{d}{dx}\left( \frac{d^{n-2}}{d^{n-2}x}\left((-1)^{n-2}x^{n-3}f'(\frac{1}{x}) \right)\right)$$
We now apply the inductive hypothesis for $f$ and $f'$ to obtain
$$ (-1)^n\frac{d^n}{d^n x}(x^{n-1}f(\frac{1}{x}))= -(n-1)\frac{1}{x^{n}}f^{(n-1)}(\frac{1}{x})-\frac{d}{dx}\left( \frac{1}{x^{n-1}}f^{n-1}(\frac{1}{x})\right)=-(n-1)\frac{1}{x^{n}}f^{(n-1)}(\frac{1}{x})-\left(-(n-1)\frac{1}{x^n}f^{n-1}(\frac{1}{x})-\frac{1}{x^{n+1}}f^{(n)}(\frac{1}{x}) \right)=\frac{1}{x^{n+1}}f^{(n)}(\frac{1}{x}). $$
